# How to sum 3 columns in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to sum a value with 3 different types:

```
'Business'
'Enterprise'
'Basic'
```

But I don't know how to query sum with different conditions.

Result must be like that:

```
SELECT
    SUM(value) WHERE Type = 'Business'
    SUM(value) WHERE Type = 'Enterprise'
    SUM(value) WHERE Type = 'Basic'`
```

I tried to create a CTE for each column, but when I join the selects, the amount value has a different result.

Comment: Look into `conditional aggregation`. If that still causes confusion after researching, then post sample data and desired results as formatted text.

Comment: What is your expected output 3 rows or 1 row with 3 columns? or just 1 value showing the sum of all 3 types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be multiple ways of doing this, but my preference is using `CASE WHEN`.

```
SELECT
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Business' THEN [value] END) as 'Business',
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Enterprise' THEN [value] END) as 'Enterprise',
   SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Basic' THEN [value] END) as 'Basic'
FROM [Table]
WHERE [Type] IN ('Basic','Enterprise','Business')
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if you want the sum for each type or the sum of all the types..

```
Select sum(value), type
From Table
Where Type in ('Basic','Enterprise','Business')
Group by Type
```

or maybe:

```
Select sum(value)
From Table
Where Type in ('Basic','Enterprise','Business')
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify on how you want your output to be.
If you need 3 columns with value sum on each type, you can always use summing using case statement as follows:

```
SELECT
   SUM(CASE Type WHEN 'Business' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) as Business_Sum
  ,SUM(CASE Type WHEN 'Enterprise' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) as Enterprise_Sum
  ,SUM(CASE Type WHEN 'Basic' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) as Basic_Sum
FROM Table
```

Or please specify if you are looking for something different

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to following problem please try executing following SQL query

```
 SELECT sum(value)
        FROM `table` group by type
```

Into above statement GROUP BY clause groups rows based on distinct value of type column and executes aggregate SUM method for value column and returns the sum of value column for each unique value of column specified into GROUP BY clause